# Lifecycle of an OpenGLAppComponent in Juce

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, vst, juce

I can't seem to get a good grasp on how these OpenGLAppComponents come and go. Can someone please correct my thinking if it is wrong?

1. Object is created that inheirts from OpenGLAppComponents and Timer. Object exists in the AudioProcessorEditor.
2. Call initialise() (This is where we attach to an openGLContext? A timer is started.)
3. addAndMakeVisible(&my_gl_appcomponent); is called from the editor, telling it that this will be drawn.
4. my_gl_appcomponent.setBounds(...) is called specifying the size and location of the GL component.
5. The timer callback calls repaint() repeatedly, updating your display.
6. When the editor is closed, we call shutdown(), where we detach from the openGLContext.
7. Delete my_gl_component, calling shutdownOpenGL() in the destructor
8. We are free to open the editor again, goto 2.

Am I missing anything? Do I have extra things? I've been trying to find the cause of this GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION error for the second day in a row and I'm getting pretty frustrated.